# Tailwind css classes not showing in Storybook build

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, storybook

I am trying to build my storybook with tailwind css. When running `build-storybook` the components are rendered with the tailwind classes. Unfortunately, when I build storybook and run the create build `storybook-static` with `npx http-server storybook-static` the classes are not loaded into the stories and the components are displayed not styled.

This is a repro repo of my project:
https://gitlab.com/ens.evelyn.development/storybook-issue

This is my `main.js` :

```
    const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/components/**/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/components/**/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    {
     name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
     options: {
       postcssLoaderOptions: {
         implementation: require('postcss'),
       },
     },
   },        
   "@storybook/addon-actions",
    "storybook-tailwind-dark-mode"
  ]}
```

My Projectstructure looks like this:

```
.storybook 
src
  components 
     subdir
       Button
         index.tsx
         button.stories.js 
  styles
    index.css (<-- tailwindcss file)
```

Any hints or advice is very appreciated.

Comment: How are you including your other styles?

Comment: @Pytth I am only using tailwindcss for the moment so my only styles are located in src/styles/index.css

Answer (score 16, accepted):

UPDATE: My original answer could be useful to others, so I'll leave it for reference. However, in this case, the problem was in tailwind.config.js.

Change

```
purge: {
    mode: 'all',
    content: [
      './src/components/**/**/*.{ts, tsx}'
    ],
  },
```

to

```
purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
```

ORIGINAL:

Just tested it out and storybook builds as expected for me. I think the key difference in our configurations is that I am not making changes to Storybook's webpack config in main.js. Rather, I am using [@storybook/addon-postcss](https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-postcss) for postcss@^8 (required for tailwind@^2):

```
// main.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  addons: [
    ...
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
      options: {
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require('postcss'),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I specify the necessary plugins in a postcss.config.js (in my project root):

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  }
```

It's also worth noting that I import Tailwind directly in Storybook's preview.js instead via my own css file:

```
// preview.js
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
export const parameters = {...}
```

Hopefully, making those changes will get Tailwind working for you.

For comparison (see comments below), here are the contents of my build storybook-static directory:

[image: contents of storybook-static directory]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately this aproach did not work for me either. Does it make any difference where my tailwindcss.css file is located or named?

Comment: I think we would need to look into Storybook's default Webpack config. I am surprised that your index.css is getting copied to the build directory. I'll attach the contents of my built storybook-static to my answer for comparison.

Comment: If you post a repro repo, I can take a look.

Comment: thank you that is very nice of you. I just removed the line that my index.css is part of the storybook-static. I added it will try/error via -s flag when building storybook. When I look at my storybook-static then it looks the same as yours. I will try and setup repro repo. Thanks a lot. i really appreciate it!

Comment: I posted a repro repo in my question

Comment: Got it: I'll add to my answer above.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Btw, I've pushed a repo to Github with a few more potentially helpful changes: 1) I recommend using Tailwind's new JIT mode; 2) your tsconfig includes were a little broken; 3) I included a pattern for writing stories in Typescript: https://github.com/jcamden/SO-68020712-revised/commit/aa09bc0db6fd71846aa66006f311b0feeabc23f5

Comment: `import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';` worked for me

Comment: You saved my life! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 14):

The above solutions will not work for Tailwind version > 3.0 because of JIT compiler.

> **Solution 1: Easy solution**

in `.storybook/preview.js` file add this line to compile tailwind generated css  files like this -

```js
import '!style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
```

Here `tailwindcss/tailwind.css` is the tailwind css file. Look, important is I've to add `!postcss-loader!` to compile tailwind generated css.

You can add also your custom scss file like this if any -

```js
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../src/scss/style.scss';
```

Here `../src/scss/style.scss` is custom scss file.

For most of the people this will work in Tailwind version > 3.0 without any issue.

> **Solution 2: Kinda Hack solution**

Create a custom styled element in preview page

```js
import tailwindCss from '!style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader!tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
const storybookStyles = document.createElement('style');
storybookStyles.innerHTML = tailwindCss;
document.body.appendChild(storybookStyles);
```

Hope, this will help for new Tailwind users who are working in Tailwind greater than `v3.0`.

Comment: added this but the `disabled:opacity-25` class still doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: Can you try extending tailwind.config.js by adding this -

variants: {
        extend: {
            opacity: ['disabled'],
        },
},

Comment: My custom styles in `index.css` alson still doesn't work in storybook, but works in normal react app. Open to your thoughts too...

Comment: Your first solution worked perfectly for me with Gatsby 4.2.0, TailwindCSS 3.1.7, PostCSS 8.4.14, @storybook/react 6.5.10.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem. My problem was solved by adding:
`import "../src/index.css";` to .storybook/preview.js

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well in a Vite + Vue 3 project.

Comment: What a life-saver of an answer!

Comment: thanks also work for my react `18.2.0`

Answer (score 4):

The following configuration will enable so Tailwind generate CSS as new tailwind classes are added to the markup in dev mode (hot reload).

In summary, I don't think @storybook/addon-postcss works with Tailwind JIT and Storybook hot reload, and the workaround is to use the `postcss-loader` webpack loader.

Install these deps:

`@storybook/builder-webpack5`
`@storybook/manager-webpack5`
`postcss-loader`
`webpack` (must be version 5)

```js
// .storybook/main.js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    // {
    //   name: "@storybook/addon-postcss",
    //   options: {
    //     postcssLoaderOptions: {
    //       implementation: require("postcss"),
    //     },
    //   },
    // },
  ],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    builder: "webpack5",
  },
  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "postcss-loader",
          options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

```js
// .storybook/preview.js
import "../styles/globals.css";

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};
```

```js
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

Comment: This worked for me after upgrading to webpack 5

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still having this problem and is using postcss >= 8, I suggest you to do as following.
Add this to tailwind.config.js

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
  content: [path.join(__dirname, "./src/**/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)")],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {}
  plugins: [],
}
```

Add this to preview.js

```
import "!style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!tailwindcss/tailwind.css"

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

This has helped me fix the problem and I hope it can help you too

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Next.js: Try these

1. [Storybook Next.js Recipe](https://storybook.js.org/recipes/next)
2. [Storybook TailwindCSS Recipe](https://storybook.js.org/recipes/tailwindcss)

---

**NOTE** : In step 2 of the tailwindcss storybook recipe, where you need to ***Provide Tailwind to stories***, the guide suggests importing `tailwind.css` file in `.storybook/preview.js` as mentioned [here](https://storybook.js.org/recipes/tailwindcss#2-provide-tailwind-to-stories).

But for my setup, there was no separate `tailwind.css` file, what worked for me instead was that I imported `globals.css` file from default Next.js file structure setup as:

In `.storybook/preview.ts`:

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
```

Provided that tailwind directives are added to `globals.css`: This is how my globals.css starts like -

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
...
```

So, in conclusion, I believe any css file containing base directive imports of tailwindmight just work (I might be wrong) when imported in preview.ts... what I showed above might just work for most Next.js users.

Please leave a comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: Snapshot of webpages as of when this answer was posted, as there are possibilities that links might have been updated/moved or content has been updated.

1. [Next.js Recipe on 12th Feb 2024](https://web.archive.org/web/20240212013800/https://storybook.js.org/recipes/next)

2. [Tailwind Recipe on 12th Feb 2024](https://web.archive.org/web/20240212014048/https://storybook.js.org/recipes/tailwindcss/)

Answer (score 1):

if you using storybook with TSdx and tailwind css you should be able to import a CSS into components

1. To be able to import your CSS into components, you will need to tell
   TSDX how to include it with your code. For that, you will need to
   install rollup-plugin-postcss (as TSDX uses rollup).
2. Create a CSS file in your src directory which we will use in any
   component in which we want to use Tailwind.

Alright, so now let's add rollup-plugin-postcss:

```
yarn add -D rollup-plugin-postcss
```

TSDX is [fully customizable](https://tsdx.io/customization) and you can add any rollup plugin, but be aware that it overrides the default behavior

Now you'll create a

> tsdx.config.js

```js
// tsdx.config.js

const postcss = require('rollup-plugin-postcss');

module.exports = {
  rollup(config, options) {
    config.plugins.push(
      postcss({
        config: {
          path: './postcss.config.js',
        },
        extensions: ['.css'],
        minimize: true,
        inject: {
          insertAt: 'top',
        },
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
};
```

This is giving a postCSS path, which tells it what files you want it to run on. The minimize key is to allow you to minimize the output. The most important key here is the "inject". you set it to "top" to tell postCSS where inside the  of our page the CSS will be inserted. It's paramount for Tailwind as it needs to have the utmost priority of any other stylesheet.

Next, for part 2, you will create a tailwind.css (can be named anything else) file under the src directory and paste this in:

```
// src/tailwind.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Add the CSS import statement to your component

```html
// src/Thing.tsx

import React, { FC, HTMLAttributes, ReactChild } from 'react';

// ! Add the CSS import statement !
import './tailwind.css`;

// ...

// we'll add some Tailwind classes on our components to test

export const Thing: FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-5/6 m-auto text-2xl text-center text-pink-700 uppercase bg-blue-300 shadow-xl rounded-3xl">
      {children || `the snozzberries taste like snozzberries`}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to create a storybook while using Tailwind CSS, you will notice that the CSS is not being applied. There is a simple solution that has helped me.

Your `preview.js` should be like.

```
  export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};
```

And you will need to add the following line in the `preview.js` to fix it.

// Add the below import line

```
  import "!style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!tailwindcss/tailwind.css";

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};
```

However this will be a temporary fix.
To get this resolved completely, you will need to add the below mentioned package.

```
yarn add -D @storybook/addon-postcss
```

For reference, click here
[How to add postcss](https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-postcss)

Comment: This is working for me partially. When I try to use @apply on a css module and import it into the component, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes @apply its not working for me ether

Answer (score 1):

The solutions mentioned above worked but only partially.
I was facing 2 issues:

1. If I added new classes to stories then tailwind was not adding corresponding styles associated with the classes.
2. Hot reloading wasn't working.

**Solution**:
Add the path to the stories folder in the tailwind.config.js file.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./stories/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", //needed to make hot reload work with stories
  ],
  theme: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't work this out and the above answered didn't work for me, so I eventually just set my build-storybook script to run tailwind itself after the build. package.json scripts looked like this in the end:

```
"build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public && $(npm bin -g)/tailwindcss -i storybook-static/static/css/main.*.chunk.css -o storybook-static/static/css/main.*.chunk.css -m",
```

Bit of a mess, but `$(npm bin -g)/` here uses my globally installed (`npm i -g tailwindcss`) version of tailwindcss as the version installed to the project wasn't working in builds for me.

-i and -o specifies the input and output files, and -m minifies the output.

I can foresee this causing problems if more than one CSS file gets built (maybe using `storybook-static/static/css/**/*.css` would work instead?), but this might help someone just get something working.