# How to setup Storybook with Tailwindcss, ReactJS and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, storybook

How do you setup Storybook so that it parses Tailwindcss styles and also parses absolute paths?

Note: This is a self-documenting question/answer allowed as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This took a while to figure out and I'm sure many others will encounter this.

Comment: The official guide on https://storybook.js.org/recipes/tailwindcss seems to work fine for me, and is simpler than the existing answer.

Comment: @BenButterworth This question arose because of issues with absolute paths and hot reloading tailwind styles when changing your code with storybook. Not sure if the official docs covers these now, if it does, then by all means official is best. If not, this can be a helpful supplement to the official docs. Feel free to let us know if those two items are covered for people finding this in the future as of June 2023 - if you'd like. For me personally, I ended up just using nextjs as a storybook (creating a site with a sidebar, main area & components) cuz it was causing too many issues for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To resolve paths in Storybook, we'll be using tsconfig as the source.
We assume you have installed a ReactJS project with the typescript template already.

### Setting Absolute Paths

#### 1. Define absolute paths in typescript

Add your absolute paths under "paths" in `tsconfig.js`.

```json
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "#assets/*": ["./assets/*"],
      "#components/*": ["./components/*"],
      // etc.
    }
  }
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

#### 2. Extend the tsconfig absolute paths to work in Storybook

Install the [tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) from npm. Has millions of weekly downloads at time of writing.

```
$ npm install -D tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin
// or
$ yarn add -D tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin
```

Under `.storybook/main.js` extend the tsconfig path resolution by adding the following to your module.exports.

```js
// .storybook/main.js

const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // Add the following block of code in addition to what's existing
  "webpackFinal": async (config) => {
    config.resolve.plugins = [
      ...(config.resolve.plugins || []),
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        extensions: config.resolve.extensions,
      }),
    ];
    return config;
  },
};
```

[Source](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack/#typescript-module-resolution)

### 3. Parsing Tailwind Styles in Storybook

Add the following two lines of code at the top of your `.storybook/preview.js` file.

```js
// .storybook/preview.js

import '!style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70805809/12894626)

Your tailwindcss should parse now.

#### Additional files

For Tailwind v3+, make sure your `tailwind.config.js` doesn't have the purge option and doesn't explicitly state JIT. Mine looks like this:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: I am doing something similar and I have the base tailwind styles working, but the color scheme I set in theme.extends isn't loading. Were you able to get anything like that working? Ex: `extends: { colors: primary: { DEFAULT: '#438D42' } }`

Comment: @kauffee000 not sure if you copied it exactly but it should be `extend:{}` no s, not `extends:{}`